# having trouble importing lit-html project into another via script tags

Tags: polymer, mime, lit-html

I would like to use the tags from my LitHTML project in another Project but Im running into `script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html".` errors.

my LIThtml project is hosted on firebase, ive tried using the polymer build tools, and open-wc but I cant seem to get around the issue.

has anyone had any luck importing a LIThtml project via a  ?

if so, is there anything specific I need in my package.json, polymer,json etc?

Thank you

Comment: How are you exactly importing? `<script type="module" src="">` ??